# React native App stuck after pressing hardware Back Button

Tags: react-native

I am using React native router-flux for navigation.

From my sidebar, there is a link to navigate to add address Screen.

After the API submission of address details, app redirects to the home screen.

For adding another address, again moved to add address Screen, then without adding an address, just press back button.

On Pressing Back button App redirect to Home screen but my app completely stuck, and I cannot perform any actions.

Here is my code for BackHandler. Please Help

```
componentDidMount(){


    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.backAndroid())

  }

componentWillUnmount(){


    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.backAndroid())

  }

backAndroid() {

    Actions.drawer1();
    return true

  }
```

Comment: try with return false instead of return true in backAndroid() method

Comment: put a log or alert in `backAndroid(){ ... }`, is that method is calling or not? is yes then `Actions.drawer1()` might have issues.